# Как записать положение input в localstorage?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Этот скрипт скрывает блоки, у которых присутствует класс `viewsfull`. Нужно как-то запомнить положение `input`, скрывать блоки или нет.

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="1"> 
<label for="news">Скрыть новости</label>

$('#news').on('change', function(){
     $('.boxx').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
           $(this).toggle()
        }
     }) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую `localStorage` и `is(':visible')`. Все работает, записывает место положения.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(localStorage.getItem('view') == 0)
{
  $('#news').prop('checked', true);
  $('.boxx').find('.viewsfull').closest('.boxx').css('display','none');
}
$('#news').on('change', function(){
     $('.boxx').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
           $(this).toggle();
          if($(this).is(':visible'))
          {
            localStorage.setItem('view',1)
          }
          else
          {
            localStorage.setItem('view',0)
          }

        }
     }) 
})
```

})

Comment: У меня этих блоков с `.boxx` несколько и после перезагрузки скрываются все блоки, а не только те, которые скриптом были скрыты. Может к этим блокам свой `id` прописать. Пример http://codepen.io/stopani/pen/RKJgeZ

Comment: надо чтобы все новости скрывались?

Comment: Нет, только те, где есть в `<a` класс `viewsfull` как в примере.

Comment: проверьте код в ответе, я изменил

Comment: Теперь правильно работает, как  теперь только `input` настроить. Чтобы если новости скрыты, то и `input` был с галкой и наоборот. А то он сейчас даже если блоки скрыты он не нажат, и не понятно скрываешь их или наоборот, потому-что это происходит на другой странице.

Comment: сделал , теперь работает, посмотрите в ответ

Comment: Всё работает. Только не пойму, если я поставлю `('opacity','0.4')` вместо `('display','none')` , почему по `toggle()` они скрываются?

Comment: С ('opacity','0.4') работать не будет, он распознает display:none, а так он его не убирает

Comment: Почему, если `input` на другой странице, где нет блоков, то он не работает?

Comment: дайте пример кода, что не рабботает

Comment: Пример кода ваш в ответе, а `input` который в вопросе. Если этот `input` на странице с новостями которые он скрывает, то он работает, а если этот `input` вынести куда нибудь в профиль, где нет новостей, то он уже не работает.

Comment: Проще говоря работает только на главной странице, с любой другой страницы не работает.

Comment: так ему необходимы новости которые он будет скрывать, иначе никак